# WebStorm Mocha is missing reporter when used with remote Node interpreter

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm

I am developing project that only "work" on a remote machine. For that I'd like to run Mocha tests using remote Node interpreter. I configured Mocha to use `sshConfig://remote/user/bin/node` (see attached image). The terminal runs the command but I get an error saying:

```
✖ ERROR: TypeError: Could not load reporter "/tmp/ik4ab6CEKm/mochaIntellijReporter.js":

 Error: Cannot find module './mochaIntellijTree'
```

I can run the tests (those that are suitable) using local Node interpreter without any problem. Actual command executed:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /path/to/project/parsers/a/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --require ts-node/register --loader=ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --timeout 30000 --ui bdd --reporter /tmp/ik4ab6CEKm/mochaIntellijReporter.js /path/to/project/parsers/a/test/DownloadFileOnRemoteServerTest.ts
```

It appears that `mochaIntellijReporter.js` specified by WebStorm does not exist on the remote machine. What do I need to install on remote machine to enable Mocha support via remote Node interpreter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-53090](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53090/Cant-run-tests-via-SSH-interpreter-Error-Cannot-find-module-mochaIntellijTree), please follow it for updates; I can't suggest any workarounds for it unfortunately